# Is it possible to control cayenne logging at a Bean level - in order to stop logging passwords

Tags: apache-cayenne

While running **Cayenne** with a Java application in **DEBUG** Mode, the cayenne operations are visible - **passwords** can be seen in the logs, when a password is changed.

Unable to find information about **controlling logging at a bean or class level.**
The log looks something like !MESSAGE [batch bind: 1->USERPWD:'1923a3d170120bb7709ef2f733c0cd...', 2->SECURID:19]

It would be good to stop logging all password related changes

Answer (score 1):

Your password is hashed (which is great), and the hash is trimmed, so you are not exposing much. But if you want to be extra cautious, you can install your own `JdbcEventLogger`:

```java
ServerRuntime rt = ServerRuntime.builder()
   .addModule(b -> b.bind(JdbcEventLogger.class).to(MyJdbcEventLogger.class)
   ....
```

In Cayenne 4.1 for `MyJdbcEventLogger` you can subclass `Slf4jJdbcEventLogger`, overriding its `appendParameters` to check for parameters that look like passwords. In 4.0 `appendParameters` is a private method, so you may have to copy/paste the entire `Slf4jJdbcEventLogger` in your code and make the changes there.